# Set a label in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have made a Google Maps with x different pins. When I hover over a pin I can see the html code:

```
['Company a<br>\
Address x, Dk-2750 <br>\
<a href="#">Show way</a>
```

I have tried to set a title and a label, so I can choose what the text should be when hover over a pin. Does anybody knows how I can set a label on a pin when hovering over a pin?

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var center = {lat: 56.2639, lng: 9.5018};
    var locations = [
      ['Company a<br>\
      Address x, Dk-2750 <br>\
     <a href="#" alt>Show way</a>',   55.730097, 12.375905],

      ['Company b<br>\
      Address y, Dk-6600<br>\
     <a href="#">Show way</a>', 55.769726, 12.497519],

      ['Company c<br>\
      Address z, Dk-6950<br>\
      <a href="#">Show way</a>', 56.110692, 8.322713],
    ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: center
    });
  var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
  var marker, count;
  for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
        map: map,
        title: locations[count][0]
      });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, count) {
        return function () {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[count][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, count));
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should add one more event listeler below the google.maps.event...
you can try `google.maps.events.addListener(marker,'hover',function(..){...})` or something like this. like i sad, i'm just guessing :)